# Traslate from sqlserver to oracle(10g)

Tags: .net, sql-server, oracle10g

First of all, sorry about english and my ignorance.  It's likely that the concepts I'm talking about are wrong (I really don't know much about oracle/pl-sql)... 
but i need ask!

I'm using a program developped in .net that was initially  developped with SqlServer and then was updated to use Oracle(10g).
Now, the program can be configured to use sqlserver or oracle.

In order to update his database it executes each related file for Oracle or SqlServer so there are files with scripts for oracle or sqlsever.

I need traslate several tables(and their related objects, constraints, create secuences and triggers for the ID columns, etc.) from SqlServer to Oracle (10g version).

The problem is I need to perform this task by scripts and these scripts have to be executed without errors, no matter how many times have been executed before.

Now the problem is how to translate those objects from sqlserver to oracle(10g) checking if the objects exist before creating sqcuences and triggers for primary keys, etc.

In SqlDevelopper there is an option to traslate from sqlserver to oracle but I can't check if the related objects exist before so my only option now it's use
pl/sql to perform the objects creation, this include using dynamic sql ( execute immediate).

my question is: is there other way to perform this task more reliable and easy?

Eventually, I suppose my only option will be spend time creating customs scripts with pl/sql using dynamic sql, checking if the objects exists before...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

As I know where is no command copy from MSSQL and paste to ORACLE(joke).
I have some experience a short time ago. First of all you should analyze tables and column data types, not all data types  can be converted from mssql to oracle, I have problem with uids, large text etc. It will be good If you had a professional DBA with experience in both DB. You maybe, will have problems with MQSQL Server and ORACLE versions compatibility 64/32bit versions. Another problem maybe related to char sets conversions. If there is a limited count of table, I mean that you can write pl/sql code in appropriate time, I think it will be best solution, all the more so can control all data pump process.